# Google Map embed for Antarctica shows wrong location

Tags: google-maps

I want to display the current location of a research ship students at my University are currently on.  Their location is off the coast of Antarctica, but the embed code I get from that page shows a bar in NY named "Antarctica".

```
https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=S+63%C2%B048'++W+066%C2%B012'&data=!1m4!1m3!1d17155058!2d-66.2!3d-63.8!2m1!1e3!4m14!2m13!1m12!3m8!1m3!1d346321!2d66.2!3d63.8!3m2!1i1440!2i805!4f35!4m2!3d-63.8!4d-66.2&fid=
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working for me... I copied your URL directly and it displays a part of Antarctica- How are you embedding it? Perhaps you could create a 'jsbin' or 'jsfiddle' to recreate your problem. That would make it a lot easier for people to help... EDIT: also, note that the url has an apostrophe in several places. This is why your link above stops at B048 instead of using the whole link.

Comment: That's my bad.  The issue is still real though.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Seems to be working for me...  I copied your URL directly and it displays a part of Antarctica-  How are you embedding it?  Perhaps you could create a 'jsbin' or 'jsfiddle' to recreate your problem.  That would make it a lot easier for people to help...  EDIT: also, note that the url has an apostrophe in several places.  This is why your link above stops at B048 instead of using the whole link.